# Как узнать NetBios имена через C#?

Tags: c#

Приветствую!

Решил начать изучение шарпа сразу с нелегкой задачи, в ходе разработки программы дошел до момента, когда мне надо узнать нетбиос имя хоста, ip которого опрашивает Ping.

Делаю все в консольном приложении. Адреса берет из файла (если нет, создает по умолчанию), далее пингует пул адресов, нужно, чтобы параллельно пингу возвращал имя хоста.

Заодно очень был бы благодарен за ссылки на разные статейки или примеры кода, в которых c# используется для работы по сети и для разных административных задач.

Answer (score 3):

Ответы Сергея и Алексея чуточку неточны: они ведут речь по `DNS`-имена, которые, во-первых, могут отсутствовать, во вторых - могут отличаться от `NetBIOS`-имени.

Далее, насколько помню, в `.net` отсутствует прямая возможность резолвить `netbios`-имена по IP. Связано это с тем, что Microsoft активно старается уйти от `netbios`-имен в сторону `DNS` (и это в какой-то степени правильно). Но, по старой памяти (давно не пишу под винды), весь функционал `NetBIOS` сосредоточен в `netapi32.dll`. Думаю, изучение интерфейса этой библиотеки Вам поможет. Там буквально одна функция, которая за все команды и отвечает.

Ну и заодно - ссылка про то, как устроен и работает NetBIOS Name Service: http://www.protocolbase.net/protocols/protocol_NBNS.php

P.S. А вот имя текущей машины `NetBIOS` доступно по проперте `System.Environment.MachineName`.

P.P.S. Еще, если не путаю, посмотрите `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` - возвращает, кажется, `DNS`-имя текущего хоста - вдруг понадобится.

P.P.P.S. К сожалению, нет под рукой ни Винды, ни дотнета - не могу проверить. Потом скажете, получилось или нет ;)

Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("93.158.134.203");
Console.WriteLine("host: " + ip.HostName);
```

Сборка System.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается при помощи запроса к DNS серверу. Сервер возвращает значение из обратной таблицы host | ip. Реализацию именно для C# не подскажу.