# Получение информации об удаленном хосте

Tags: c#, c++

Как получить имя пользователя удаленного хоста в локальной сети по ip адресу?

Comment: в  общем - никак. Там может не быть пользователя. Или удаленный хост может быть маленькой железякой, у которой само понятия пользователя отсутствует как класс.

Comment: имею ввиду имя учетной записи

Comment: вообще ответ "Никак" -не верный. в крайнем случае можно вызвать строку ping -a IP и распарсить ответ на предмет существования перед квадратными скобками имени. Но наверника есть способ лучше. Будет время - подумаю.(следует хорошенько изучить класс PingReply)

Comment: согласно документации - [ping -a](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=ping&category=8) - это пинг с звуковым сигналом. Это точно никак не поможет.

Comment: Я сам думал пропарсить диапозон ip адрес , но а дальше что да и как...
Допустим имя компа и мак адрес без проблем получить можно по ip адресу , а непосредственно имя учетной записи? Как? В каком направлении нужно копать?

Comment: Если вы в *nix, то команда `who` покажет кто сейчас находится на локальной машине вместе с IP  с которого произведен вход. Историю таких заходов можно получить командой `last`. / (подозреваю, это не совсем то, что вас интересует)

Comment: Ответ "Никак" - верный. Строго верный - "В общем случае никак", потому что при определённых условиях (наличие прав, наличие на удалённом хосте сервисов, гарантированное наличие там строго одного интерактивного сеанса и т.п.) узнать имя текущего пользователя на удалённом хосте всё-таки возможно и. главное, сама задача будет иметь хоть какой-то смысл. Но вообще мне кажется, что автор хотел спросить вовсе не то, что спросил... просто у него не получилось, а понять его никто не смог.

Comment: думаю, на самом деле автор хотел спросить о том, как получить пользователя на "винде по айпи". @xSx ему это также подсказывает :) Но что бы понять, насколько вопрос обширный, можно посмотреть на железяку с названием "WiFi Module - ESP8266"...

Comment: @avp , да,  меня это не очень интересует, тк получить имя учетной записи на локальном пк труда особого не составляет :), а получить имя учетки удаленно - вот это да))). Наверное весь инет облазил , но ничего дельного не нашел, а самое  интересное то,что я не знаю в какую сторону копать...

Comment: `whois/rwhois` -- но практически это всюду закрыто. Другими словами вопрос у вас следующий (для *nix) -- "как прочесть `/etc/passwd` на заданном IP в той же локалке?" или что почти то же самое  -- "как зайти на хост не зная логина?"

Comment: Тут встает вопрос -- а к какому оборудованию в этой сетке вы вообще  имеете доступ? Суть в том, что вам надо будет читать wireshark (или чем-то вроде) пакеты в сети (и тогда уже можно думать дальше)

Comment: видимо, не правильно понял) Если есть доступ можно вытащить из AD

Comment: @xSx , но как привязать имя учетки из AD к ip?

Comment: Не уверен, на счет стандартных способов, чаще всего сисадмины прибегают к логон-логоф скриптам, которые красиво заносят пользователей, которые часто меняются. А так если все хорошо вносилось, может и net view /domain:ad > somefile.txt помочь, проверить можно и net view /all. А вытаскивать из АД шарпом хорошо получается(если автор не случайно указал c#в теге)

Comment: @xSx, да я на шарпе пробовал

Comment: А вам зачем? Если вы пишете внутренний сайт, и ставите Windows аутентификацию, то вам в заголовках будет передано и имя компа, и имя юзверя. Вобщем скажу так, что при сетевом соидинении "не используется" имя пользователя, поэтому вы его можете получить только если пользователдь подключается вам от своего (или чужого) имени, например http, ftp, rdp, smtp и многие другие протоколы поддерживают "пользователя". Нужно понимать что часть программ на компе работают под пользователем, а часть "под рутом".

Comment: По IP вы можете получить имя хоста, используя DNS. На с# так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/10327/17974

Comment: @nick_n_a, сканер сети пишу. Программы на типе "ip scanner" не очень подходят под нужные задачи и поэтому решился написать программу под свои нужды.